# Javascript: How to show hide divs based on security role

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security

I have been using **JQuery** and **AngularJS**. One requirement I had was to show/hide divs and other widgets based on the **login user role**. I implemented the solution as below:-

- On page load, get role of logged in user and store as a global variable in javascript
- Show complete page
- Hide divs using simple if statements based on security role
  Is this the best way? Isn't there some framework or library for this? Doesn't *AngularJS* have anything to help?

Btw I understand that server side security is a must in spite of controlling what widgets login user can see in browser.

Comment: Do you have any server side authentication like passportjs, I recommend taking a look at the mean.js boilerplate code. They implement passportJs serverside authentication and then they create an angular "Authentication" service to store the user. Then all you have to do is ng-if="Authentication.user.role = 'user role'"

Answer (score 0):

You could look at something like Angular Schema Forms. This takes a JSON object and will render it out using templates as HTML.

Another approach would be to use a template for each widget and then check the role before retrieving the template. If the template isn't retrieved then your custom tags will remain empty and have no content.

```
if isAuthorized
    get template
else
    do nothing or remove the element (your call)
```

The benefit of the first is that your markup is generated from server side data and thus has the extra benefit of being more secure. The second will work as well however.

Answer (score 0):

Do note that you can change ANYTHING in javascript including global variable and javascript code in client side, so your server CANNOT TRUST THE CLIENT.

It's fine if you want to show/hide div based on the global variable, but your server should NEVER use that global variable to determine user permission. And for the div's that are hidden, you should NOT populate them with data from DB, so even when client change the CSS, they can't see data that is not permitted. Not to mention they can always inspect the network to see what is inside the JSON returned.

Usually you don't need to store as global variable, though. If your user does proper authentication, you should verify his identity for every transaction (every ajax request) and return only relevant content. In Angular view you can do `ng-if` when data exists only.